# How to apply functions with multiple arguments on Pandas selected columns data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = {'gene':['a','b','c','d','e'],
        'count':[61,320,34,14,33],
        'gene_length':[152,86,92,170,111]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df[["gene","count","gene_length"]]
```

That looks like this:

```
In [9]: df
Out[9]:
  gene  count  gene_length
0    a     61          152
1    b    320           86
2    c     34           92
3    d     14          170
4    e     33          111
```

What I want to do is to apply a function:

```
def calculate_RPKM(theC,theN,theL):
    """
    theC  == Total reads mapped to a feature (gene/linc)
    theL  == Length of feature (gene/linc)
    theN  == Total reads mapped
    """
    rpkm = float((10**9) * theC)/(theN * theL)
    return rpkm
```

On to `count` and `gene_length` columns and a constant `N=12345`
and name the new result as 'rpkm'.
But why this failed?

```
N=12345
df["rpkm"] = calculate_RPKM(df['count'],N,df['gene_length'])
```

What's the right way to do it?
The first row should look something like this:

```
 gene  count  gene_length rpkm
   a     61          152  32508.366
```

**Update:** the error I got is this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-6270e1d19b89> in <module>()
----> 1 df["rpkm"] = calculate_RPKM(df['count'],N,df['gene_length'])

<ipython-input-1-48e311ca02f3> in calculate_RPKM(theC, theN, theL)
     13     theN  == Total reads mapped
     14     """
---> 15     rpkm = float((10**9) * theC)/(theN * theL)
     16     return rpkm

/u21/coolme/.anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in wrapper(self)
     74             return converter(self.iloc[0])
     75         raise TypeError(
---> 76             "cannot convert the series to {0}".format(str(converter)))
     77     return wrapper
     78
```

Comment: If it fails please print the exact error message you are getting. This makes it much easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't cast to `float` in your method and it will work fine:

```
In [9]:
def calculate_RPKM(theC,theN, theL):
    """
    theC  == Total reads mapped to a feature (gene/linc)
    theL  == Length of feature (gene/linc)
    theN  == Total reads mapped
    """
    rpkm = ((10**9) * theC)/(theN * theL)
    return rpkm
N=12345
df["rpkm"] = calculate_RPKM(df['count'],N,df['gene_length'])
df

Out[9]:
  gene  count  gene_length           rpkm
0    a     61          152   32508.366908
1    b    320           86  301411.926493
2    c     34           92   29936.429112
3    d     14          170    6670.955138
4    e     33          111   24082.405613
```

The error message is telling you that you cannot cast a pandas Series to a `float`, whilst you could call `apply` to call your method row-wise. You should look at rewriting your method so that it can work on the entire `Series`, this will be vectorised and be much faster than calling `apply` which is essentially a `for` loop.

**Timings**

```
In [11]:

def calculate_RPKM1(theC,theN, theL):
    """
    theC  == Total reads mapped to a feature (gene/linc)
    theL  == Length of feature (gene/linc)
    theN  == Total reads mapped
    """
    rpkm = ((10**9) * theC)/(theN * theL)
    return rpkm
​
def calculate_RPKM(theC,theN,theL):
    """
    theC  == Total reads mapped to a feature (gene/linc)
    theL  == Length of feature (gene/linc)
    theN  == Total reads mapped
    """
    rpkm = float((10**9) * theC)/(theN * theL)
    return rpkm
N=12345

%timeit calculate_RPKM1(df['count'],N,df['gene_length'])
%timeit df[(['count', 'gene_length'])].apply(lambda x: calculate_RPKM(x[0], N, x[1]), axis=1)

1000 loops, best of 3: 238 µs per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 1.5 ms per loop
```

You can see that the non casting version is over 6X faster and will be even more performant on larger datasets

**Update**

The following code along with using the non-casting `float` version of your method is semantically equivalent:

```
df['rpkm'] = calculate_RPKM1(df['count'].astype(float),N,df['gene_length'])
df

Out[16]:
  gene  count  gene_length           rpkm
0    a     61          152   32508.366908
1    b    320           86  301411.926493
2    c     34           92   29936.429112
3    d     14          170    6670.955138
4    e     33          111   24082.405613
```

Comment: If I remove `float` then this  `calculate_RPKM()` will give 0 on stand alone case.

Comment: Can you give me sample input that produces `0`, you could just change the line to this in your method: `rpkm = ((10**9) * theC)/(theN * theL).astype(float)`

Answer (score 1):

The [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method takes a parameter `axis` which when set to 1 sends the whole row into the apply function. This makes it a lot slower than a normal apply function since it is no longer a proper [monoid lambda function](http://fmota.eu/blog/monoids-in-python.html). But it does work.

Like this:

```
N=12345
df["rpkm"] = df[(['count', 'gene_length'])].apply(lambda x: calculate_RPKM(x[0], N, x[1]), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be fixed simply by removing the float requirement in the function definition, the operation is applied down the two series entirely:

```
def calculate_RPKM(theC,theN,theL):
    """
    theC  == Total reads mapped to a feature (gene/linc)
    theL  == Length of feature (gene/linc)
    theN  == Total reads mapped
    """
    rpkm = ((10 ** 9) * theC)/(theN * theL)
    return rpkm

df['rpkm'] = calculate_RPKM(df['count'], N, df['gene_length'])
```

The output of `df['rpkm']`

```
0     32508.366908
1    301411.926493
2     29936.429112
3      6670.955138
4     24082.405613
Name: rpkm, dtype: float64
```

If you want to be entirely sure that the output is a float you could pass the two series in changed to floats:

```
counts = df['count'].astype(float)
lengths = df['gene_length'].astype(float)

df['rpkm'] = calculate_RPKM(counts, N, lengths)
```